# copying a long long array to integer array in c language

Tags: c

I want to copy a long long array to an integer array using `memcpy()`. The size of the long long array is half of the size of the integer array.

Other than `memcpy()` I've used this:

```
int *dst;
long long src[10];
dst=(int*)src;
```

But I want to use only `memcpy()`.

Because the purpose is, the long long array is a temporary array, which copies its contents, to the sub arrays of source array. The source array is a 2 dimensional array .

Comment: I'm almost sure you don't _want_ to do that..but then ,....

Comment: Your example does not even do a copy, but just a pointer cast.

Answer (score 3):

In general, `sizeof (long long) > sizeof (int)`.

So you cannot copy all elements in an array of `long long` into an array of `int` using a byte-by-byte copy operation such as `memcpy()`; the data won't fit.

You can use a loop, to manually do the (truncating) copy. This will of course lose information:

```
const long long incoming[] = { 1ll, 2ll, /* more here ... */ };
int out[sizeof incoming / sizeof *incoming];
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof incoming / sizeof *incoming; ++i)
  out[i] = (int) incoming[i];
```